# Right ML mode and metric to minimize FN and FP on imbalanced dataset

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, sampling, class-imbalance

So I have a dataset in which I have to predict class binary label (1 or 0), the problem, out of 120k data points, only 200 have the label '1'.
the aim is to minimize FN and FP.

1. Which  ML model should I use? Gradient boost or XGBoost or logistic regression. How do I calculate the class weights?
2. Which accuracy metric captures the minimization of FP and FN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you use class weights, I don't think it would make much of a difference which model you use (regarding the imbalance). If you are familiar with python, I would suggest [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html) sklearn function that could help you out in computing the class weights. However, I have found that **oversampling** (or undersampling) often works better than class weights. Consider using [SMOTE](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html) for this.
2. While there are metrics and loss functions better suited at handling class imbalance ([GMS](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.metrics.geometric_mean_score.html), [quadratic kappa](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score.html), etc.) I don't think you would have an issue with using any loss 
   if you considered oversampling your data.